# How to add timed mute to discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm making a discord bot and i want to add a timed mute function like in other moderation bots where you can say who you want to mute and for how long. I have done muting in general but now need the timed mute stuff so please help me. I am also not very good with Javascript so please tell me where i implement the code if you give me some. The mute file:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "mute",
  description: "mutes the mentioned user",

  execute(message, args) {
    const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      (role) => role.name === "muted"
    );

    const target = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!mutedRole) {
      message.channel.send("Cannot find mute role.");
    } else {
      target.roles.add(mutedRole);
      message.channel.send("Muted " + target + " ✅");
    }
  },
};
```

i want it that its -mute {user} {time}
an example is: -mute @ani 10s

if you want the main file here you go:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "!";

const fs = require("fs");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ani Bot is online!");
  client.user.setActivity("with depression");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "test") {
    client.commands.get("test").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "mute") {
    client.commands.get("mute").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "unmute") {
    client.commands.get("unmute").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "join") {
    client.commands.get("join").execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === "leave") {
    client.commands.get("leave").execute(message, args);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `setTimeout()` right after you mute a user.

```
//you call the function unmuteUser after 10000 milliseconds
setTimeout(unmuteUser(user), 10000);

function unmuteUser(user){
   //code that unmute
   ...
}
```

Comment: but how do i get it to work based on the time i give it. for example how do make it work for 1 hour if i say 1h

Comment: You should get the time from the message, convert it into milliseconds and replace it instead of the 10000 ms.